# PHP display array in array in array

Tags: php, arrays

I want know how to access to array in array in array in php.

The result with `$user` is this:

```
'pages':{'x','y','z','access':{'a':3,'b':6,'c':8,'contact':2}}
```

How I can access to contact, please?

Comment: Are you sure it is an array?

Comment: look likes a format of json to me

Comment: can you provide us the full JSON ?

Comment: The result is neither an array nor a valid JSON.

Comment: indeed invalid, so what is that ?!

Comment: the result is this: "id":1,"active":1,"canAccess":{"entities":{"1":{"name":"blablabla","services":{"45":{"name":"xxx"}}}}},"blabla":null,"pages":{"acces":{"notifications":1,"contact":2}}

Answer (score 1):

First of all this is JSON (probably), so before we can access it with php we need to decode it using json_decode which will give you a php object. (i made it valid JSON)

```
$jsonString = '{"pages":{"x": 0,"y": 0,"z": 0,"access":{"a":3,"b":6,"c":8,"contact":2}}}';

$phpObject = json_decode($jsonString);

var_dump($phpObject->pages->access->contact);
// prints int(2)
```

Comment: with json_decode the answer is NULL, but with "var_dump($user->pages);" i can see: array(1) { ["acces"]=> array(32) {        
        ["notifications"]=> int(1) ["contact"]=> int(2) 
         } }

but i can't access to contact!

thanks for your help

Comment: json_decode returns NULL if the string in not valid json. So i think you will need to look at that first. You can check it here: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Well, i get the contact's value with $user->pages['acces']['contact'];

thank you everybody!

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode` to convert this to array in PHP (if it is JSON)

Comment: It is not a json. at least not valid one

Answer (score -1):

It seems your string missing `{}` around.

```
{
 "id":1,"active":1,"canAccess":{"entities":{"1":{"name":"blablabla","services":{"‌​45":{"name":"xxx"}}}}},"blabla":null,"pages":{"acces":{"notifications":1,"contact‌​":2}}
}
```

then it  is a valid JSON string.

```
var_dump(json_decode($string,true));
```